# contract.methods.function(arg).send() not working in browser console although same line of code working in node console

Tags: web3js

```
//contract abi................
const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'constructor'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'number',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function'
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'retrieve',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function'
  },
  {
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'store',
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'function'
  }
];
       


         // web3 instantiation
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

        const retrieve = async () => {
            await ethereum.enable();

            const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();                                  
            //contract instance
            const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, 
                       "0x5CdA988C848d2Fb6426F05521B1FE84128323bc0");

             await contract.methods.store("572357").send({from: 
                       accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});
        
             const num = await contract.methods.retrieve().call();
            console.log(num);
           

        }
        retrieve();
```

getting error in browser console

```
index.ts:205 Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid tuple value (argument="tuple", value="572357", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.0-beta.153)
```

Comment: Most likely package versions in Node and browser are different, or other similar dependency problem.

Comment: Problem solved now. Above given abi is an array of objects and web3 works with JSON. Now derived the abi from Remix which worked flawless. Thank you very much for help!